# How can I add delete button on list?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have project for beginning for `html` `javasicript` but I trying something.
I want to add list delete button but ı don't know how can I add a delete button for each line ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <header><h1></h1></header>
  <section>
   
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <div>
        <label for="newitem">Add item</label>
        <input type="text" name="newitem" id="newitem" 
               placeholder="new item" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
      </div>
    </form>
     <ul id="todolist"></ul>
  </section>
  
<script>
(function(){

  var todo = document.querySelector( '#todolist' ),
      form = document.querySelector( 'form' ),
      field = document.querySelector( '#newitem' );
    
  form.addEventListener( 'submit', function( ev ) {
    var text = field.value;
    if ( text !== '' ) {
      todo.innerHTML += '<li>' + text + '</li>';
      field.value = '';
      //field.focus();
    }
    ev.preventDefault();
  }, false);



})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <header><h1></h1></header>
  <section>
   
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <div>
        <label for="newitem">Add item</label>
        <input type="text" name="newitem" id="newitem" 
               placeholder="new item" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
      </div>
    </form>
     <ul id="todolist"></ul>
  </section>
  
<script>
(function(){

  var todo = document.querySelector( '#todolist' ),
      form = document.querySelector( 'form' ),
      field = document.querySelector( '#newitem' );
    
  form.addEventListener( 'submit', function( ev ) {
    var text = field.value;
    if ( text !== '' ) {
      todo.innerHTML += '<li>' + text + ' <button onclick="Delete(this);">Delete</button> </li>';
      field.value = '';
      //field.focus();
    }
    ev.preventDefault();
  }, false);



})();
  function Delete(currentEl){
  currentEl.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(currentEl.parentNode);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to use other div using without  onclick="Delete(this)

Comment: Sorry @Naveen007, I didn't get you what you want to do. So can you please tell me in brief.